# Developing Musical App for Windows

Tags: c++, c, audio

I have musical app developed for OS X, which has following features,

- Play multiple tracks at a time (long audio files and short sounds)
- rewind, forward, pause, stop functionality
- the app also displays the waveform of the song
- Create playlist

I used Apple's Core Audio framework for music playback.

Now I have to develop the same application for Windows. I don't have any experience of working on Windows.

Any idea, Which IDE to use? It must has Audio frameworks (as close to Core Audio)

Also, want some suggestions on which approach can we take so development will be easy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the IDE I'd suggest CodeBlocks: http://www.codeblocks.org/. Visual C++ (as suggested by D.A. White) you will have to pay for as soon as you sell any of the stuff you programmed with it, if I am not mistaken. I would also prefer OpenAL ( http://www.openal.org) to DirectSound, because OpenAL should also work on the Mac. So in the future you only have to write the code once, and simple compile it once against Windows and once against Mac OS X.

Good luck, Audiodroid

Answer (score 4):

You can get Visual C++ 2010 Express for free. You can either use OpenAL or DirectSound.